# Помогите объединить пустые ячейки <td>через colspan на PHP

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, парсер, std-regex

Имеется текстовая переменная, в которой содержится HTML-таблица вида:

```html
.......
<tr class="myclass1">
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
.......
<tr>
  <td class="myclass2" colspan="12">
    Text
  </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
.......
```

Хочу уменьшить количество пустых ячеек  внутри каждого столбика , объединив их через

```
<td colspan="количество пустых ячеек"></td>.
```

Проблема в том, что в разных столбцах при этом может содержаться различное количество пустых ячеек .
Объединить нужно только пустые ячейки (или содержащие пробельные символы).
То есть преобразование из моего примера должно выглядеть так:

```html
.......
<tr class="myclass1">
  <td colspan=4></td>
</tr>
.......
<tr>
  <td class="myclass2" colspan="12">
    Text
  </td>
  <td colspan=2></td>
</tr>
.......
```

Как можно реализовать это регулярным выражением?
Насколько я понимаю, нужно будет каким-то образом рекурсивно сделать это через preg_replace, но как при этом определить где и сколько замен?

Comment: А зачем????????

Comment: Чтобы уменьшить длину строки. Пустых ячеек может быть очень много.

Comment: а почему не воспользоваться HTML парсером?

Comment: Это преобразование из таблицы excel в html. Часть парсинга делает компонент excel reader 2.22, который и выводит таблицу таким образом. Далее ее очищает PHP-класс Tidy. Остальное обрабатывает мой скрипт, осталось только пустые ячейки объединить, которых может быть достаточно много.

Answer (score 0):

Если элементы будут максимально простыми (без атрибутов), то следующий код может помочь в требуемой группировке.

```php
$str = <<<'HTML'
.......
<tr class="myclass1">
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
.......
<tr>
  <td class="myclass2" colspan="12">
    Text
  </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
.......
HTML;

$spaceCharsPattern = <<<'PCRE'
(?:\t|\n|\v|\f|\r| |\xC2\x85|\xc2\xa0|\xe1\xa0\x8e|\xe2\x80[\x80-\x8D]|\xe2\x80\xa8|\xe2\x80\xa9|\xe2\x80\xaF|\xe2\x81\x9f|\xe2\x81\xa0|\xe3\x80\x80|\xef\xbb\xbf)
PCRE;

$result = preg_replace_callback("~(?:$spaceCharsPattern*<td>$spaceCharsPattern*</td>){2,}~", function ($matches) {
  preg_match_all("~<td>$spaceCharsPattern*</td>~", $matches[0], $subMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
  $subMatchesCount = count($subMatches);
  return "<td colspan=\"$subMatchesCount\"></td>";
}, $str);

echo $result;
```

Данный код должен вернуть результат

```html
.......
<tr class="myclass1"><td colspan="4"></td>
</tr>
.......
<tr>
  <td class="myclass2" colspan="12">
    Text
  </td><td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
.......
```

В коде используется функция `preg_replace_callback` для поиска сгруппированных пустых тегов `<td>`, для каждой найденной группы будет вызываться функция.

Далее используется функция `preg_match_all` с флагом `PREG_SET_ORDER` для того что бы результаты в `$subMatches` в первом вложении были сгруппированы по найденным результатам (сколько пустых `<td>` было найдено в группе пустых).

Переменная `$spaceCharsPattern` служит для возможности конфигурировать допустимые пробельные символы между `<td>`, если это требуется. Начальным и самым простым набором пробельных символов будет `\s`.

Comment: А если элементы будут с атрибутами, например одни <td class="myclass"> </td>, другие <td class="myclass"> </td>, а третьи <td></td>, итд?

Comment: @tim68, в таком случае встаёт вопрос о необходимости их объединения. Как собирать эти атрибуты в целевом `<td>`?

Comment: Давайте оставим их пустыми, т.к. конечная ячейка <td colspan="n"></td> также будет пустой, видимой границы она иметь не будет и атрибуты ей не понадобятся.

Comment: Также пробельные символы в содержимом ячейки встречаются довольно разные, и \s лучше всего будет заменить на (\t|\n|\v|\f|\r| |\xC2\x85|\xc2\xa0|\xe1\xa0\x8e|\xe2\x80[\x80-\x8D]|\xe2\x80\xa8|\xe2\x80\xa9|\xe2\x80\xaF|\xe2\x81\x9f|\xe2\x81\xa0|\xe3\x80\x80|\xef\xbb\xbf)

Comment: @tim68, добавил возможность конфигурирования пробельных символов и вставил этот паттерн.

Comment: Конструкция вида          <td class="c1"></td>
          <td class="c1"></td>
          <td class="c1"></td>
          <td class="c1"></td>
осталась без colspan

Comment: Насколько я понял, конструкции  <<<'PCRE' ... PCRE; и <<<'HTML' ... HTML; - для Perl а не для PHP?

Comment: Ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or T_END_HEREDOC or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN in parce.php on line 197 - я так понял, опечатка в "~<td>$spaceCharsPattern*</td>"' - в конце нужно ставить ~" ?

Comment: @tim68, _"конструкции <<<'PCRE' ... PCRE; и <<<'HTML' ... HTML; - для Perl а не для PHP"_ — это [`howdoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) и это PHP.

Comment: @tim68, _"Конструкция вида <td class="c1"></td> <td class="c1"></td> <td class="c1"></td> <td class="c1"></td> осталась без colspan"_ — верно, как и написано в ответе, — этот способ работает только для максимально простых (без атрибутов) тегов `<td>`. Если нужна агрегация атрибутов, то лучше уже смотреть в сторону работы с HTML как с DOM (например, через [встроенный функционал PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php)).

Comment: Плюсанул Вам, к сожалению от новичков плюсы не отображаются. Я не сильно разбираюсь в howdoc, сделал немножко проще, свой вариант кода описал ниже.

Comment: howdoc — это более удобный способ записи многострочных строк. Начинается с `<<<'FOO'` вместо `'` и заканчивается на новой строке `FOO` вместо `'`. (Вместо `FOO` можно написать что удобнее, главное что бы в начале и в конце были одинаковые сочетания). Использовал лишь для удобства.

Answer (score 0):

Помог ответ 7-zete-7, огромное ему спасибо, виден специалист высокого уровня.
К сожалению, его код сработал не совсем так, как нужно, но помог понять принцип.
Вот что я сделал для оптимизации, возможно поможет остальным:
Сначала убрал пробелы внутри всех не пустых ячеек:

```
<td ...> n </td> ---> <td ...>n</td>
 
$spaceCharsPattern="\t|\n|\v|\f|\r| |\xC2\x85|\xc2\xa0|\xe1\xa0\x8e|\xe2\x80[\x80-\x8D]|\xe2\x80\xa8|\xe2\x80\xa9|\xe2\x80\xaF|\xe2\x81\x9f|\xe2\x81\xa0|\xe3\x80\x80|\xef\xbb\xbf";
     $$html_table=iconv('Windows-1251','UTF-8',$html_table);
     $pattern = "/<td(.*?)>($spaceCharsPattern)*([^\r\n]+)($spaceCharsPattern)*<\/td>/";
     $replacement='<td$1>$3</td>';
     $price_table=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $html_table);
     $price_table=iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1251',$html_table);
```

Потом вычистил пробелы и атрибуты из пустых ячеек:

```
   <td ...>   </td> ---> <td></td>
 
$html_table=iconv('Windows-1251','UTF-8',$html_table);
 $pattern = "/<td(.*?)>($spaceCharsPattern)*<\/td>/";
 $replacement='<td></td>';
 $html_table=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $html_table);
 $html_table=iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1251',$html_table);
```

А затем объединил пустые ячейки через colspan:

```
$html_table = preg_replace_callback('~(?:\s*<td>\s*</td>){2,}~', function ($matches) {
 preg_match_all('~<td>\s*</td>~', $matches[0], $subMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
 $subMatchesCount = count($subMatches);
 return "<td colspan=\"$subMatchesCount\"></td>";
 }, $html_table);
```

Comment: Пытайтесь избегать создания не нужных групп в регулярных выражениях. Группы увеличивают сложность (в плане производительности) работы регулярного выражения. Не берите в скобки то, что не должно быть сгруппировано (что не нужно потом использовать). Если сгруппировать небоходимо, но созданная группа не будет нужна, — добавьте `?:` в начале группы что бы, например, вместо `(foo|bar)` получилось `(?:foo|bar)`.

Comment: То есть как в этом примере - (?:\s*<td>\s*</td>){2,} группа нужна только для того, чтобы показать количество повторений, верно?